# Moving Sketch's iOS UI Design Library to Symbols Page

Tags: sketch-app

Sketch has iOS symbols embedded. It's difficult for me to find the symbols I'm looking for by just looking at the names in the dropdown menu as shown below.

[image: iOS Symbols]

I can't seem to find how I can view all these symbols at once in a symbols page, or how to move them to a symbols page. Here's an screenshot of another file - ideally the symbols in the library would be laid out in a page like this. Any suggestions on how I can view all the iOS symbols in the dropdown on a page?

[image: Symbols Page]

Answer (score 1):

Symbols pages are sketch file specific, so you need to add the elements to your sketch Design, and using the "Create Symbol" button, add them to your symbols page for that file.

Sketch does now support Libraries, which are files just for holding a ton of symbols, and you set those by going into the Preferences and adding individual files AS libraries - this is what you'll want to do, as that way these symbols will be available in multiple Sketch files - but bear in mind this means you can only EDIT those symbols in the original Library file: this helps with control and worksharing, but may be a pain for a solo designer.

See the documentation for more details:

https://sketchapp.com/docs/libraries/

Hope this helps.